# Bold String in java than send that String to printer

Tags: java, string, printing

String which we like to bold is **PlayTime** which converted in unicode with external url as shown in below code and than in picture after printing it.

here is code snippet:

```
String BILL = "\n \uD835\uDC0F\uD835\uDC0B\uD835\uDC00\uD835\uDC18\uD835\uDC13\uD835\uDC08\uD835\uDC0C\uD835\uDC04 \n";
    BILL =  BILL + "Albert I Promenade 53 & 89 Oostende \n";
    BILL = BILL + "0496 11 01 12 \n";
```

used this link to covert simple text into bold and it turned out be like this:[url used for converting string into bold](https://lingojam.com/BoldTextGenerator)

[image: image attached showing garbage value at top and bottom]

Comment: Have you checked the printer's documentation?

Comment: Depends entirely on the printer and printer driver.

Comment: (It should probably read "Thank you for ordering from us", unless you actually *are* ordering them, but human trafficking is generally frowned upon, or if you mean "bossing us around" then you'd want it to read "Thank you for giving us orders" or similar.)

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah i got the point of changing that text but currently I'm focusing on bold text.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp nothing fancy in the printer doc. is there any method of lib i can use to bold the text in java ?

Comment: The “bold characters” are actually part of Unicode’s Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block.  Using them for any purpose other than math formulae is a hack and a misuse of the characters.

Comment: There's no generic "make this text bold", it depends on the printer. I mean, you don't even provide *that* information, which may or may not work anyway. It depends on the printer. It might use special control characters, it might use HTML, it might use PDF, it might use PCL (none of those are likely), it might use a bitmask like the Adafruit thermal printers (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Thermal-Printer-Library/blob/master/Adafruit_Thermal.cpp), there's just no way for us to know.

Comment: [here is ink of printer](https://www.gadgetstrading.nl/58mm-bluetooth-4-0-pos-receipt-thermal-printer.html?fee=1&fep=57149&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google+shopping&utm_term=paid)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be the existence of control sequences:

```
String wide = "\u001b!\u0020" + "PlayThing" + "\u001b!\u0000";
String emphasized = "\u001b!\u0008" + "PlayThing" + "\u001b!\u0000";
```

For that one would need the capabilities of the printer.

Comment: I have tested that as well and the result for them is ! PlayThing!
and yes printer can print bold characters : [here is link to printer](https://www.gadgetstrading.nl/58mm-bluetooth-4-0-pos-receipt-thermal-printer.html?fee=1&fep=57149&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google+shopping&utm_term=paid)

one more things if the size of string can be increased it will also serve the purpose.

Comment: That were some Esc/POS standard escape sequences, which obviously did not work. I think you are out of luck. You can look whether you find the used thermal printer in the net.

Comment: how about we can add the text logo on the top ? will that print ?

Comment: Why not? "P l a y T i m e" or such.

Comment: yeah that will be last case.